# Javascript syntax error reported by DW

Tags: javascript, jquery, dreamweaver

```
$("#file_description").focus(function() {
        if (this.value === this.defaultValue) {
            this.value = '';
        }
  });
```

Dreamweaver CS6 is reporting a syntax error on line two, what am I overlooking or is this a parser error? Thanks!

Comment: what is the error message

Comment: What you've posted looks fine.

Comment: Does Dreamweaver recognize that jQuery is included?  Otherwise the "$" could be throwing it off.

Comment: thanks a bunch for the reply, not enough coffee noob mistak did not post the whole snippet. sorry if I wasted your time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's no error there. Consider it a Dreamweaver bug.

Comment: $("#file_description").focus(function() {
        if (this.value === this.defaultValue) {
            this.value = '';
        }
  
  })
  
  .blur(function() {
        if (this.value === '') {
            this.value = this.defaultValue;
        }
});